# C sprintf - could you please explain the following?

Tags: c, printf

What is the meaning of the following line:

```
sprintf(version, "%ld%c", tpdu->version, sep);
```

I am getting confused in `"%ld%c"`. How is it used here?

Comment: With all due respect, RTFM first. (That's a _saying_, nothing personal).

Comment: @SouravGhosh: The OP might be confused by the lack of space between the two format specifiers. The OP might be a beginner, and he might think that `"%ld%c"` is a single format specifier, that he is unable to decipher. An answer telling him to split this specifier into two parts (`%ld` and `%c`) would be better than "RTFM". This community should be more welcoming and more beginner friendly.

Comment: @Mr.C64 Please have a look at the timeline. Already two answers are posted. After that I made the comment, As long as I know, a question should reflect the research efforts which this one particularly lacks.

Comment: @Mr.C64 and by saying beginner friendly does not mean we can welcome _skipping_ [Ask] part.

Comment: @SouravGhosh With all due respect , please go ahead and close the tab!!!

Comment: @SouravGhosh: The fact that two answers were already posted before your comment doesn't mean anything to me. To me, it seems just a question from someone who is a C beginner (and I think everyone of us once was).

Comment: @Mr.C64 We all have our own viewpoint and I respect that. To me `I am getting confused in "%ld%c"` does sound like `I don't know what is meant by "%ld%c"`, rather than `i'm confused not by seeing a space separator between two format specifiers, is this a desired behaviour?`.

Answer (score 6):

`%ld%c` are two format specifiers `%ld` and `%c`. The former is used for a `long int` while the latter is used for a `char`.

The `sprintf` you have writes the value of `tpdu->version`, a `long int` and the value of `sep`, a `char` into the buffer `version`.

Answer (score 1):

The line says

Store the value of `long int` `tpdu->version` and `char` `sep` to the buffer `version`.

`%ld` is a format specifier for `long int` and `%c` for `char`

Comment: sprintf(buf, " %ld; " , tpdu->errindex, sep);

Comment: format specifier %ld; , here semi colon is used?  Why so

Comment: @user3125224 No need of semicolon I don't see such thing in the question you asked

Answer (score 0):

To better understand it, you have to mentally split the whole format specifier `"%ld%c"` into its more basic tokens. If you split at every % sign, you get: `%ld` and `%c`.

`%ld` is a placeholder for a `long int`.

`%c` is a placeholder for a `char`.

So, the whole statement:

> ```
> sprintf(version, "%ld%c", tpdu->version, sep);
> ```

prints a `long int` (i.e. the content of the `tpdu->version` field) followed by a `char` (i.e. the content of the `sep` variable) into a string buffer named `version`.